# Network unreachable after Ubuntu VM movement

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, network-manager, oracle, virtualbox-networking

**Setup**: I am using VirtualBox 6.1.40 r154048 (Qt5.6.2). Windows 11 host OS. VM is Ubuntu 22.04.1. VM is using HostOnly Network adaptor.

**Initial Status**: Ping was working from Windows to a VM and vice-versa. Internet was reachable from the VM.

**Operation Performed**: Moved the VM from the external HDD to the internal HDD.

**Problem**:
The Internet is unreachable from the VM. Ping is not working from VM to Windows. However, Ping is working from Windows to the VM.

The problem persists even after upgrading to the latest VirtualBox 7.0.10 r158379.

In fact, the problem is not seen with some of the other VMs, which were moved across HDD.

Why is this issue seen?

syslog is kept at https://github.com/bhuvanplus/logs/blob/main/syslog

**Debugging done on the VM:**

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

$ ip -a
br-41ececd2e647: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255

enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.61.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.61.255

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s3
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-41ececd2e647
192.168.61.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3

$ sudo ufw status
Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
43/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
53/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
43/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
53/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

$ lsmod | grep vboxguest
vboxguest             430080  7 vboxsf
```

Comment: Initially, "HostOnly" doesn't support internet. If you want the internet on your VM, you should use "bridge mode". Or Internet can be achieved on VM with "HostOnly Adapter" with some iptables rules on Host. But of course, you should remove Windows and install *unix system on your Host